# How to augment `ElementAttrs<HTMLAttributes>` interface in Vue?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, tsx

I'm using Vue 3 with TSX, how to augment the `ElementAttrs<HTMLAttributes>` interface, so I could do the following without getting type errors?

```
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    //                                 ts complains
    return () => <div class='v-table' vLoading={true}></div>
  },
})
```

The error I got is:

```
Type '{ class: string; vLoading: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'ElementAttrs<HTMLAttributes>'.

Property 'vLoading' does not exist on type 'ElementAttrs<HTMLAttributes>'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured this out:

```
// Import an entire module for side effects only, without importing anything.
// This runs the module's global code but doesn't actually import any values.
import 'vue'

declare module 'vue' {
  interface HTMLAttributes {
    vLoading?: unknown
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you edit or create this file?

Comment: @ChrisW You can put it under `src/types/vue.ts` like so.

Comment: In our project, we had to `declare module 'vue/types/jsx' {}`