# Property 'dataToggle' does not exist on type 'ElementAttrs<AnchorHTMLAttributes>' vue3 and typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs3

**Issue**

I am attempting to use a bootstrap4 snippet to create nav bar menu in my vue 3 application -

```
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
```

However, I am getting the following error from the compiler -

> Type '{ class: string; href: string; id: string; role: string;
> dataToggle: string; "data-toggle": string; ariaHaspopup: string;
> "aria-haspopup": "true"; ariaExpanded: string; "aria-expanded":
> "false"; }' is not assignable to type
> 'ElementAttrs'.   Property 'dataToggle' does not
> exist on type 'ElementAttrs'.ts(2322)

The drop down menu doesnt not work as a result...why is this?

**EDIT**
shims-vue.d.ts file -

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
  export default component
}
```

Comment: how do you create your project?

Comment: using the vue cli

Comment: do you have `shims-vue.d.ts` file?

Comment: i do indeed.....

Answer (score 2):

Create new `bs.d.ts` with content

```
import "vue";

declare module "vue" {
  interface HTMLAttributes {
    dataToggle?: string;
  }
}
```

and it to "include" in your `tsconfig.json`.

---

Original answer: [How to augment `ElementAttrs<HTMLAttributes>` interface in Vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67632314/how-to-augment-elementattrshtmlattributes-interface-in-vue)