# How to extend HTMLAttributes interface in Vue, so it works in template?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have the same problem as in [How to augment `ElementAttrs<HTMLAttributes>` interface in Vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67632314/how-to-augment-elementattrshtmlattributes-interface-in-vue). I want vue-tsc to not complain about data-testid attributes from Cypress on HTML native elements (with strictTemplates mode on), but I don't use TSX, but just Vue SFC with nor template syntax. I tried extending the interface in the above question but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting "dataAttributes: ["data-testid"] under vueCompilerOptions in tsconfig.json solves my problem.